# Use a macro in a range reference

Tags: string, vba, excel

```
bottom = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=countblank('[Test.xlsx]Sheet1 test'!C1:C1)"
```

I am trying to use the "bottom" value in my range !C1:C1). I want to be able to count the value of missing cells in a column. I tried several combinations but I couldn't find a way of making it work. 
For example if bottom is 10, I want it to count the missing values in column 1 up to row 10.

Comment: If you add the function in a `Module` and make it public, you can use it in the Excel formulas, you can also pass parameters to it.

Comment: `Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=countblank('[Test.xlsx]Sheet1 test'!C1:C" & bottom & ")"`

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I had an extra " at the end. Thank you, it worked. Range("A2").Formula = "=countblank('[Test.xlsx]Sheet1 test'!A1:A" & bottom & ")"

Comment: The general consensus is that fixing a quoted string to be inserted as a cell's formula via VBA is **not** an [tag:excel-formula] problem.

Answer (score 0):

The title of *Use a macro in a range reference* is a bit misleading.

From the title I'd suggest using this code:

```
Public Function MyRange() As Range

    Dim rng_bottom As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1 Test")
        Set rng_bottom = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        Set MyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 3), rng_bottom.Offset(, 2))
    End With

End Function
```

You can then enter directly into a cell: `=COUNTBLANK(MyRange())` which would use a macro as a range reference.

From your sample code it looks more like you want one of these three solutions:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim rng_bottom As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1 Test")
        'Return a reference to the last cell in column A.
        Set rng_bottom = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

        '****SOLUTION 1:****
        'Add the formula using R1C1 formatting.  Offset rng_bottom by 2 columns to return reference to column C.
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=COUNTBLANK('Sheet1 Test'!R1C3:" & rng_bottom.Offset(, 2).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ")"
    End With

    Dim lng_bottom As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1 Test")
        'Return last row number in column A.
        lng_bottom = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        '****SOLUTION 2:****
        'Add the formula using R1C1 formatting.
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=COUNTBLANK('Sheet1 Test'!R1C3:R" & lng_bottom & "C3)"

        '****SOLUTION 3:****
        'Add the formula using A1 formatting.
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Formula = _
            "=COUNTBLANK('Sheet1 Test'!$C$1:$C$" & lng_bottom & ")"

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UDF that returns the used range in a column

```
Function UsedRange(r As Range, Optional FromRowOne As Boolean = True) As Range
    Dim rTop As Range
    Dim rEnd As Range
    With r.Worksheet
        Set rTop = r.EntireColumn.Cells(1, 1)
        If Not FromRowOne Then
            If IsEmpty(rTop) Then
                Set rTop = rTop.End(xlDown)
            End If
        End If
        Set rEnd = r.EntireColumn.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)
        If IsEmpty(rEnd) Then
            Set rEnd = rEnd.End(xlUp)
        End If
        If rTop.Row < rEnd.Row Then
            Set UsedRange = .Range(rTop, rEnd)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

To count the number of empty cells in column A use it like this

```
=COUNTBLANK((UsedRange(A:A)))
```

Optional parameter `FromRowOne` can be used to ignore blanks from row 1 down to the first used row, like this

```
=COUNTBLANK((UsedRange(A:A, FALSE)))
```

If it is passed an empty column, it returns `Nothing`

It also accounts for the possibilty that data extends to the last row in the sheet